# Java/Hibernate: Decompressing a compressed result

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, compression

I'm trying to decompress a value returned with MySQL's COMPRESS function:

```
SQLQuery query = session
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, COMPRESS(TEXT_COL) AS TEXT_COL FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,...);")
            .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.INTEGER)
            .addScalar("TEXT_COL", Hibernate.TEXT);
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
for (Object[] result : list) {
   String text = decompress(((String) result[1]).getBytes());
}

(...)
private String decompress(byte[] bs) {
    InputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bs));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while((len = in.read(buffer))>0)
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        return new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

And I'm getting java.lang.AssertionError: java.util.zip.ZipException: **incorrect header check**

What's the way to decompress such mysql result or what's wrong with my code?

Thanks in advance,
Diego.

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Joni for the suggestions, I finally changed the code to

```
SQLQuery query = session
            .createSQLQuery("SELECT ID, COMPRESS(TEXT_COL) AS TEXT_COL FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,...);")
            .addScalar("ID", Hibernate.INTEGER)
            .addScalar("TEXT_COL", Hibernate.BINARY);
List<Object[]> list = query.list();
for (Object[] result : list) {
   String text = decompress(((byte[]) result[1]));
}

(...)
private String decompress(byte[] bs) {
    InputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bs, 4, bs.length-4));
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
        int len;
        while((len = in.read(buffer))>0)
            baos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        return new String(baos.toByteArray(), "UTF-8");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new AssertionError(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to skip 4 bytes in the beginning of the stream:

```
InputStream in = new InflaterInputStream(
                     new ByteArrayInputStream(bs, 4, bs.length-4));
```

This is because the [`COMPRESS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_compress) function returns a string where the first four bytes give the length of compressed data and the following bytes are the actual compressed data.

Also, you should try to find a way to obtain the result directly as bytes. The compressed result is binary data and probably cannot be converted safely into a String.

Comment: Thank you, I was on the track: I had seen in a php forum the question about the first 4 bytes.